# How to directly map a Lua variable to a C++ variable?

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, mapping, lua

I am working on a game engine in C++ using Lua to define NPCs.

I can define a prototypic NPC like this:

```
orc =
{
    name = "Generic Orc",
    health = 100
}

function orc:onIdle()
    print("Orc idles...")
end
```

and then spawn an instance of "Orc" with `entitySpawn(orc)`. This is a C++ function that reads values like health and name from the given table, creates an Entity object in C++ with the given values and in addition creates a Lua table for the specific NPC.

Now, I would like to have a direct connection between the `orc.health` variable in Lua and the `mHealth` member variable of the corresponding Entity object in C++, so I could assign a value in Lua and instantly use it in C++ and vice versa.

Is this even possible? Or do I have to make use of setter / getter functions? I have taken a look at light userdata and got to the point of storing a pointer to the C++ variable in Lua, but could not assign a value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible. I'm assuming that `entitySpawn` returns the table that C++ created for the entity. I'll also assume that you can expose a function from C++ that takes an entity's table and returns the current health, and similarly for setting. (You can use a light userdata pointer to the C++ object as a member of this table to implement this.)

So the ugly way would look like this:

```
local myOrc = entitySpawn(orc)
local curHealth = getEntityHealth(myOrc)
setEntityHealth(myOrc, curHealth + 10)
```

To make this prettier, we can have some fun with metatables. First, we'll put the accessors for all the properties we care about.

```
entityGetters = {
    health = getEntityHealth,
    -- ...
}
entitySetters = {
    health = setEntityHealth,
    -- ...
}
```

Then we'll create a [metatable](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8) that uses these functions to handle property assignments.

```
entityMetatable = {}

function entityMetatable:__index(key)
    local getter = entityGetters[key]
    if getter then
        return getter(self)
    else
        return nil
    end
end

function entityMetable:__newindex(key, value)
    local setter = entitySetters[key]
    if setter then
        return setter(self, value)
    end
end
```

Now you need to make `entitySpawn` assign the metatable. You would do this with the [`lua_setmetatable`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_setmetatable) function.

```
int entitySpawn(lua_State* L)
{
    // ...
    // assuming that the returned table is on top of the stack
    lua_getglobal(L, "entityMetatable");
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
    return 1;
}
```

Now you can write it the nice way:

```
local myOrc = entitySpawn(orc)
myOrc.health = myOrc.health + 10
```

Note that this requires that the table that is returned by `entitySpawn` does *not* have a health property set. If it does, then the metatable will never be consulted for that property.

You can create the `entityGetters`, `entitySetters`, and `entityMetatable` tables, as well the `__index` and `__newindex` metamethods, in C++ instead of Lua if that feels cleaner to you, but the general idea is the same.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I need! Seems my research went in the completely wrong direction :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have time to give you any code, but keep in mind `orc.health` is the same as `orc["health"]`; that is, `orc` is a table and `"health"` is an element.

With that in mind, you can change the `index` and `newindex` [metamethods](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8) of your table to have your own specific behavior. Store your "real" orc instance as some private metadata, then use it to update.